# Concept of Partial Derivatives in the Context of Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The concept of a partial derivative is fundamental when studying multivariable calculus.

I was wondering if there is a standard definition of partial derivatives in the context of smooth manifolds. I could not find one.

So here is my guess:

> Let $M, N$, and $P$ be smooth manifolds and $f:M\times N\to P$ be a smooth function. Let $(p, q)\in M\times N$ and define a function $i^q:M\to M\times N$ as $i^q(a)=(a, q)$ for all $a\in M$.
>   Then the **partial derivative** of $f$ with respect to $M$ at the point $(p, q)$ is $d(f\circ i^q)|_p$.

So is this definition satisfactory?

Thanks.

Comment: The notation is well defined, but most of the manifolds are not a product...

Comment: The useful notion towards what you're looking for (and how one finds a notion of PDE for smooth maps $M \to N$, or more generally smooth sections of a fibration) is that of the *jet bundle*.

Comment: @John Yes. See my comment to Autolatry's answer. 

To: MikeMiller Thanks. I 'll look it up.

Comment: Dieudonne Treatise Volume 3, beginning of chapter 17, shows that the generalization of a partial derivative to a manifold is that of a vector field.

Answer (score 1):

Bishop and Goldberg define something similar when they say the partial derivative of a funciton on a smooth manifold $M$ is given by $\partial_i f= \frac{\partial f}{\partial{x^i}}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial{u^i}}\circ\mu$, where $\mu= (x^1,...,x^d)$ is the coordinate system of a point $m\in M$, $g=f\circ\mu^{-1}$ is the coordinate expresssion for $f$ and $u^i$ are the cartesian coordinates on $R^d$. Notice the difference: $f$ is differentiated with respect to $x^i$ and $g$ with respect to $u^i$. By definition $x^i=u^i\circ\mu$.

The whole idea of differentiating with respect to manifold coordinates is extrememly abstract, however the point to always come back to is that a manifold is a curved space that allows a *local calculus*.

Comment: You have defined what a partial derivative of a smooth map $f$ defined on a smooth manifold $M$ at a given point with respect to a given smooth chart. The value of the partial derivative thus depends on the chart considered. And there is no other way to do it because there is no canonical smooth chart. For this reason, in my attempt at a definition, I considered a product manifold. Further, my definition coincides with the usual definition of partial derivatives in multivariable calculus.

Comment: The partial derivative depends on the coordinates in a vector space too. Basically the partial derivative against the $\mu$th coordinate is a directional derivative in the direction of the $\mu$th coordinate, so the *mere concept* must depend on the coordinates, just like a directional derivative depends on the vector you are differentiating against.

Comment: @Uldreth In vector spaces yes. But when you think of say $\mathbf R^2$ as $\mathbf R\times\mathbf R$, then the partial derivatives depend on what the coordinates were on $\mathbf R$. So if a vector space is $V:=U\times W$, the partial derivatives can be defined by referring to the coordinates on $U$ and $W$. That's what I tried to do in my original post.